# Android Realm return exception "Table has no columns"

Tags: android, database, relational-database, realm

This is my code:

```
  PSTrip psTrip = JsonUtil.jsonToObject(jsonObject.toString(), PSTrip.class);
int size = psTrip.getTripSteps().size()-1;
RealmList<Step> steps = psTrip.getTripSteps().get(size).getSteps();
RealmList<TripStep> tripSteps = psTrip.getTripSteps();
Log.i("","continue init after getting tripsteps and steps");
if(tripSteps.size() > 0) {
    Log.i("","continue init blabla");
    for (int i = 0; i < tripSteps.size(); i++) {
        RealmList<Step> mergedSteps = Utils.getMergedSteps(context, tripSteps.get(i).getRoute().getSteps());
        tripSteps.get(i).getRoute().getSteps().clear();
        for (Step step : mergedSteps) {
            tripSteps.get(i).getRoute().getSteps().add(step);
        }
     }
     Log.i("", "continue init after for in which I merge the steps for the tripsteps");
     steps = Utils.getMergedSteps(context, steps);
     Log.i("", "continue init after merging the steps");
     tripSteps.get(size).setSteps(steps);
     Log.i("", "continue init after settting steps on tripsteps");
     psTrip.setTripSteps(tripSteps);
 }
 PSTripDBFactory.getInstance(context).addToList(psTrip);
```

The Utils.getMergedSteps just takes the list of steps (Step from Google maps class), and if it is possible, it merges them.
My problem is at the last line which does:

```
 public void addToList(PSTrip psTrip){
    try{
        PSTrip insideAlready = getListOfCompletedTripsByID(psTrip.getId());
        Log.i("","continue init inside already:" + insideAlready);
        if(insideAlready == null){
            Log.i("","continue init will copy to realm");
            realm.beginTransaction();
            realm.copyToRealm(psTrip);
            realm.commitTransaction();
            Log.i("","continue init will copy to realm finished");
        }else{
            Log.i("","continue init will copyorupdate to realm");
            realm.beginTransaction();
            realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(psTrip);
            realm.commitTransaction();
            Log.i("","continue init will copyorupdate to realm finished");
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.i("","continue init error trying to add to realm" + e.getMessage());
        realm.cancelTransaction();
    }
}
```

Where getListOfCompletedTripsByID is the following function:

```
 public PSTrip getListOfCompletedTripsByID( String id){
    RealmResults<PSTrip> completed = realm.where(PSTrip.class).equalTo("id" , id).findAll();
    if(completed.size() > 0){
        return completed.get(0);
    }else{
        return null;
    }
}
```

I get back the following error response:

```
03-18 11:14:56.135  21908-21908/nl.hgrams.passenger I/﹕ continue init after for in which I merge the steps for the tripsteps
03-18 11:14:56.135  21908-21908/nl.hgrams.passenger I/﹕ continue init after merging the steps
03-18 11:14:56.135  21908-21908/nl.hgrams.passenger I/﹕ continue init after settting steps on tripsteps
03-18 11:14:56.135  21908-21908/nl.hgrams.passenger I/﹕ continue init inside already:null
03-18 11:14:56.136  21908-21908/nl.hgrams.passenger I/﹕ continue init will copy to realm
03-18 11:14:56.137  21908-21908/nl.hgrams.passenger D/REALM﹕ jni: ThrowingException 7, Table has no columns, .
03-18 11:14:56.137  21908-21908/nl.hgrams.passenger D/REALM﹕ Exception has been throw: Table has no columns
03-18 11:14:56.138  21908-21908/nl.hgrams.passenger I/﹕ continue init error trying to add to realmAn exception was thrown in the copyToRealm method in the proxy class  io.realm.PSTripRealmProxy: Annotation processor may not have been executed.
```

Does anyone have an ideea why does realm return me a "table has no columns" error?

EDIT:

This is my PSTrip class:

```
public class PSTrip extends RealmObject {
private boolean valid;
private String detail;
private String icon_small;
private double avgspeed;
private String type;
private RealmList<RealmObj> messages = new RealmList<RealmObj>();
private String travel_mode;
private String id;
private Owner_data owner_data;
private int distance;
private RealmObj errors;
private String name;
private String destination_status;
private double checkinLat;
private double checkinLng;
private double checkoutLng;
private double checkoutLat;
private String icon;
private String status;
private int update_interval;
private Destination destination;
private double elapsed;
private int checkout_time;
private int checkin_time;
private Route route;
private String owner;
private double delay;
private String vehicle;
private Flight flight;
@SerializedName("last_updated")
private int lastUpdated;
@SerializedName("steps")
private RealmList<TripStep> tripSteps = new RealmList<TripStep>();
private Group group;
private boolean isRoaming = false;

public boolean getIsRoaming() {
    return isRoaming;
}

public void setIsRoaming(boolean isRoaming) {
    this.isRoaming = isRoaming;
}

public Group getGroup() {
    return group;
}

public void setGroup(Group group) {
    this.group = group;
}

public int getLastUpdated() {
    return lastUpdated;
}

public void setLastUpdated(int lastUpdated) {
    this.lastUpdated = lastUpdated;
}

public RealmList<TripStep> getTripSteps() {
    return tripSteps;
}

public void setTripSteps(RealmList<TripStep> steps) {
    this.tripSteps = steps;
}

public String getVehicle() {
    return vehicle;
}

public void setVehicle(String vehicle) {
    this.vehicle = vehicle;
}

public Flight getFlight() {
    return flight;
}

public void setFlight(Flight flight) {
    this.flight = flight;
}

public boolean getValid() {
    return valid;
}

public void setValid(boolean valid) {
    this.valid = valid;
}

public String getDetail() {
    return detail;
}

public void setDetail(String detail) {
    this.detail = detail;
}

public String getIcon_small() {
    return icon_small;
}

public void setIcon_small(String icon_small) {
    this.icon_small = icon_small;
}

public double getAvgspeed() {
    return avgspeed;
}

public void setAvgspeed(double avgspeed) {
    this.avgspeed = avgspeed;
}

public String getType() {
    return type;
}

public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
}

public RealmList<RealmObj> getMessages() {
    return messages;
}

public void setMessages(RealmList<RealmObj> messages) {
    this.messages = messages;
}

public String getTravel_mode() {
    return travel_mode;
}

public void setTravel_mode(String travel_mode) {
    this.travel_mode = travel_mode;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Owner_data getOwner_data() {
    return owner_data;
}

public void setOwner_data(Owner_data owner_data) {
    this.owner_data = owner_data;
}

public int getDistance() {
    return distance;
}

public void setDistance(int distance) {
    this.distance = distance;
}

public RealmObj getErrors() {
    return errors;
}

public void setErrors(RealmObj errors) {
    this.errors = errors;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getDestination_status() {
    return destination_status;
}

public void setDestination_status(String destination_status) {
    this.destination_status = destination_status;
}

public String getIcon() {
    return icon;
}

public void setIcon(String icon) {
    this.icon = icon;
}

public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public int getUpdate_interval() {
    return update_interval;
}

public void setUpdate_interval(int update_interval) {
    this.update_interval = update_interval;
}

public Destination getDestination() {
    return destination;
}

public void setDestination(Destination destination) {
    this.destination = destination;
}

public double getElapsed() {
    return elapsed;
}

public void setElapsed(double elapsed) {
    this.elapsed = elapsed;
}

public int getCheckout_time() {
    return checkout_time;
}

public void setCheckout_time(int checkout_time) {
    this.checkout_time = checkout_time;
}

public int getCheckin_time() {
    return checkin_time;
}

public void setCheckin_time(int checkin_time) {
    this.checkin_time = checkin_time;
}

public Route getRoute() {
    return route;
}

public void setRoute(Route route) {
    this.route = route;
}

public String getOwner() {
    return owner;
}

public void setOwner(String owner) {
    this.owner = owner;
}

public PSTrip() {
}

public double getDelay() {
    return delay;
}

public void setDelay(double delay) {
    this.delay = delay;
}

public PSTrip(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public double getCheckoutLng() {
    return checkoutLng;
}

public void setCheckoutLng(double checkoutLng) {
    this.checkoutLng = checkoutLng;
}

@Override
public boolean isValid() {
    return valid;
}

public double getCheckinLat() {
    return checkinLat;
}

public void setCheckinLat(double checkinLat) {
    this.checkinLat = checkinLat;
}

public double getCheckinLng() {
    return checkinLng;
}

public void setCheckinLng(double checkinLng) {
    this.checkinLng = checkinLng;
}

public double getCheckoutLat() {
    return checkoutLat;
}

public void setCheckoutLat(double checkoutLat) {
    this.checkoutLat = checkoutLat;
}

public boolean isRoaming() {
    return isRoaming;
}

public void setRoaming(boolean isRoaming) {
    this.isRoaming = isRoaming;
}
}
```

This is my TripStep class:

```
public class TripStep extends RealmObject{
@SerializedName("travel_mode")
private String travelMode;
@SerializedName("moving_time")
private int movingTime;
@SerializedName("moving_distance")
private int movingDistance;
private Polyline polyline;
private String vehicle;
private Route route;
@SerializedName("trip_id")
private int tripId;
@SerializedName("departure_stop")
private DepartureStop departureStop;
@SerializedName("arrival_stop")
private DepartureStop arrivalStop;
@PrimaryKey
private int id;
private Transit_details transit_details;
private RealmList<Step> steps = new RealmList<Step>();
private boolean hasStarted = false;

public Transit_details getTransit_details() {
    return transit_details;
}

public void setTransit_details(Transit_details transit_details) {
    this.transit_details = transit_details;
}

public String getTravelMode() {
    return travelMode;
}

public void setTravelMode(String travelMode) {
    this.travelMode = travelMode;
}

public int getMovingTime() {
    return movingTime;
}

public void setMovingTime(int movingTime) {
    this.movingTime = movingTime;
}

public int getMovingDistance() {
    return movingDistance;
}

public void setMovingDistance(int movingDistance) {
    this.movingDistance = movingDistance;
}

public Polyline getPolyline() {
    return polyline;
}

public void setPolyline(Polyline polyline) {
    this.polyline = polyline;
}

public String getVehicle() {
    return vehicle;
}

public void setVehicle(String vehicle) {
    this.vehicle = vehicle;
}

public Route getRoute() {
    return route;
}

public void setRoute(Route route) {
    this.route = route;
}

public int getTripId() {
    return tripId;
}

public void setTripId(int tripId) {
    this.tripId = tripId;
}

public DepartureStop getDepartureStop() {
    return departureStop;
}

public void setDepartureStop(DepartureStop departureStop) {
    this.departureStop = departureStop;
}

public DepartureStop getArrivalStop() {
    return arrivalStop;
}

public void setArrivalStop(DepartureStop arrivalStop) {
    this.arrivalStop = arrivalStop;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public RealmList<Step> getSteps() {
    return steps;
}

public void setSteps(RealmList<Step> steps) {
    this.steps = steps;
}

public boolean isHasStarted() {
    return hasStarted;
}

public void setHasStarted(boolean hasStarted) {
    this.hasStarted = hasStarted;
}
}
```

The rest are mostly google maps classes.
The PSTrip RealmList messages is empty.
the Route class contains a RealmList which is not empty (thats why I try doing copy to realm on it before)

Comment: What do your model classes and JSON look like?

Comment: @Emanuelez made an edit to include my PSTrip class

Comment: You PSTrip class has a lot of references to other objects. Are any of them "empty" objects, ie. they contain no fields?

Comment: there might be empty objects, is that an problem?

Comment: Yes, RealmObjects are required to have at least one field.